# Maximizing the area inside an ellipse whilst fixing the circumference and varying the eccentricity.

Tags: geometry

So, inspired by my previous question:

[Intuition for why a rectangle with a fixed perimeter has a maximal area when L=W](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247569/intuition-for-why-a-rectangle-with-a-fixed-perimeter-has-a-maximal-area-when-l-w/4247713#4247713)

Title says it all really. In the space of ellipses with circumfrence c and parameterized by eccentricity, which ellipse has maximal area? My previous question would lead me to believe that it is when the ellipse is a circle. Can somebody help me to understand why this is?

Comment: This might help: [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

Comment: ah my man !! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the circumference $L$ of an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$, semi-minor axis $b$ and area $A$, we have the following inequality: $L \geq \pi(a+b).$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
L^2 & \geq \pi^2 (a^2+2ab+b^2) \\
& = \pi^2 ((a-b)^2+4ab) \\
& = \pi^2(a-b)^2+4\pi\cdot \pi a b \\
& = \pi^2(a-b)^2+4\pi A
\end{align}
$$
This means
$$
A\leq \frac{L^2-\pi^2(a-b)^2}{4\pi}
$$
As we can see, whenever $a\neq b$, we have $A<\frac{L^2}{4\pi}.$

But in case of a circle, we have $A = \frac{L^2}{4\pi}$

Comment: This is so great! Could you recommend me a textbook where I could learn more stuff like this?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with textbooks and material suitable for studying (I finished university 20 years ago and have not looked very often into textbooks ever since.) For this answer, I have only put together the well known formulae for the area and circumference of the circle, the area of the ellipse and a lower bound for the circumference of the ellipse (I found on Wikipedia)